# Use derived class for template constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class with a template constructor:

```
class TCons {
    template <typename T> TCons(T t);
}
```

which is specialized in the implementation:

```
template <> TCons::TCons(int i) { doMyStuff(i); }
```

I also have a specialization for a base class:

```
template <> TCons::Tcons(TBase &t) { doMyStuff(t); }
```

But this doesn't seem to work when I try to initialize a TCons object using a derived object as a parameter.

```
class TDeriv: public TBase { };
TDeriv td;
TCons tc = td;
```

I can't use a pointer to resolve this issue (since everything is wrapped inside a macro). The problem arises during the link phase.

Is it just wrong, or am I missing something?

Comment: Fix the typos and syntax so that your code compiles.

Comment: Why using specialization instead of simple overloads ?

Comment: lose the `template<>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we try to construct `tc` here:

```
TCons tc = td;
```

we have one choice of constructor:

```
template <typename T> TCons(T t);
```

When we perform template deduction, we deduce `T = TDeriv`. This does **not** match your `TBase` explicit specialization (nor the `int` one), so we stick with the primary template. You don't provide a definition for it, which is why you have a linker error.

If you want your `TBase` constructor to be called on all types that inherit from `TBase`, you'll have to disable the constructor template for those cases. We can do that with SFINAE:

```
template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<TBase, T>::value>>
TCons(T );
```

while additionally making your other constructors non-template overloads:

```
TCons(int );
TCons(TBase& );
```

Only specialize when you need to - overloading is going to simpler.

Comment: solved, but the clang syntax is a little different: template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<TBase, T>::value>::type>

Comment: @GB That's not "clang syntax", that's C++11. Even if you don't have a C++14 compiler, you should add the type trait aliases yourself - makes the code cleaner.

Comment: c++ concepts would really make the code cleaner. Now it just looks like a train wreck...